# how can I resize an animated GIF file using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to resize such an animated GIF file *do.gif* [image]

If I do `convert do.gif -resize 24x24\! do-24.gif` I get it resized in *do-24.gif* but not animated [image]

How to resize it right way to get the same animation?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

first run:

```
convert do.gif -coalesce temporary.gif
```

then

```
convert -size <original size> temporary.gif -resize 24x24 smaller.gif
```

Comment: Great! It works!!!

Comment: `-coalesce` "creates a complete view of the animation at each point, a bit like a true film strip, rather than an animation sequence. Such a sequence, known as a [Coalesced Animation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#coalesced) is much easier to study, edit, modify and re-optimize."

Comment: `gifsicle --resize 24x24 > do-24.gif` can to this too

Comment: Note that the coalesced view is much larger than the optimized one (3.2 times in my test), and the resizing produces a coalesced image, which can also be larger than the original in file size (2.3 times in my test) even if the resolution is smaller.  When I try resizing directly it looks fine and has a small file size, though maybe it just works for this image.

Comment: gifsicle produced a much better, optimized output for my use case. Thanks @sam!

Comment: gifsicle reduced quality in my case

Comment: convert temporary.gif -resize 24x24 smaller.gif works for me.,without specifying input size.

Comment: +sam wait, isn't that `gifsicle` command missing the input gif?

Comment: Yes, gifsicle command should be `gifsicle do.gif --resize 24x24 > do-resized.gif`

Comment: While the answer works (thanks!), what is the explanation simple `convert` doesn't do that?

Comment: Users will likely want to re-optimize their GIF with a `-deconstruct` after `-coalesce`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/257831/how-can-i-resize-an-animated-gif-file-using-imagemagick/1104062#1104062

Comment: Tried these commands and the gif was indeed resized. However, the file size increased 3 times. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 21):

I was looking for imagemagick solution as I am familiar with it, but in the end I went with @sam's suggestion of [`gifsicle`](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/). It did just what I wanted, no hassle.

Can optimize resulting file size in so many ways, but I went with just reducing the size and reducing number of colors. Worked like a charm:

```
gifsicle --resize 48x48 --colors 16 original.gif > smaller.gif
```

Answer (score 11):

**`-coalesce` + `-deconstruct`**

After `-coalesce`, you likely want to add a `-deconstruct`:

```
convert in.gif -coalesce -resize 256x -deconstruct out-deconstruct.gif
```

The root cause of the problem is that your input GIF was properly minimized: GIF allows the next frame to be just the modified rectangle from the previous one at an offset.

`-coalesce` then expands all the frames to the original size, which makes the resize work, but it does not re-compress the frames again as your input image: `-deconstruct` is needed for that!

Using the test data from this answer: [How do I create an animated gif from still images (preferably with the command line)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648244/how-to-create-a-gif-from-jpeg-images-with-the-command-line/1102183#1102183) we can see this clearly with `identify`:

```
$ identify out-convert.gif | head -n 3
out-convert.gif[0] GIF 1024x1024 1024x1024+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 16.7865MiB 0.020u 0:00.019
out-convert.gif[1] GIF 516x516 1024x1024+252+257 8-bit sRGB 256c 16.7865MiB 0.030u 0:00.019
out-convert.gif[2] GIF 515x520 1024x1024+248+257 8-bit sRGB 256c 16.7865MiB 0.030u 0:00.019

$ convert out-convert.gif -resize 256x out.gif
$ identify out.gif | head -n 3
out.gif[0] GIF 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 5.0479MiB 0.000u 0:00.009
out.gif[1] GIF 256x256 256x256+125+128 8-bit sRGB 256c 5.0479MiB 0.000u 0:00.009
out.gif[2] GIF 256x258 256x256+123+128 8-bit sRGB 256c 5.0479MiB 0.000u 0:00.009

$ convert out-convert.gif -coalesce -resize 256x out-coalesce.gif
$ identify out-coalesce.gif | head -n 3
out-coalesce.gif[0] GIF 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.97683MiB 0.010u 0:00.009
out-coalesce.gif[1] GIF 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.97683MiB 0.010u 0:00.009
out-coalesce.gif[2] GIF 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.97683MiB 0.010u 0:00.009

$ convert out-convert.gif -coalesce -resize 256x -deconstruct out-deconstruct.gif
$ identify out-deconstruct.gif | head -n 3
out-deconstruct.gif[0] GIF 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.87942MiB 0.010u 0:00.010
out-deconstruct.gif[1] GIF 135x135 256x256+60+61 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.87942MiB 0.010u 0:00.010
out-deconstruct.gif[2] GIF 135x136 256x256+59+61 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.87942MiB 0.010u 0:00.010
```

out.gif

[image]

out-coalesce.gif

[image]

out-deconstruct.gif

[image]

First, we see how to input file, `out-convert.gif`, was in fact compressed, since frame 2 is only `516x516` at offset `252+257`, while the full sized frame 1 is `1024x1024`.

Then, if we compare the three conversions:

- `out.gif`: All frames are `256x256` or larger, and huge at about 5MiB, TODO why?

  Visually incorrect, since those approximately `256x256` frames have a non-zero offset, e.g. `125+128` for frame 2!
- `out-coalesce.gif`: all frames are `256x256` and have the correct offset `0+0`.

  Output looks visually correct, but the output file size is 2.0 MiB, which is larger than `out-deconstruct.gif`
- `out-deconstruct.gif`: compressed frames, final output size 1.9 MiB.

  Not considerably smaller than `out-coalesce.gif`, but I think this is just because the black ground compresses really well, and it could be very significant in general.

**ffmpeg and gifsicle**

I also tried out the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i out-convert.gif -vf scale=256:-1 out-ffmpeg-small.gif
gifsicle --resize 256x256 out-convert.gif > out-gifsicle.gif
```

and both produced an even smaller correctly looking 1.5 MiB output.

See also: [How do I create an animated gif from still images (preferably with the command line)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648244/how-to-create-a-gif-from-jpeg-images-with-the-command-line/1102183#1102183)

TODO: why can they make it smaller than `convert`? Are they just selecting better more minimal diff rectangles, or something else?

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, ffpmeg 4.0.2-2, ImageMagick 6.9.10-8.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/STS-132_Liftoff_Space_Shuttle_Atlantis.ogv
ffmpeg -i STS-132_Liftoff_Space_Shuttle_Atlantis.ogv -r 15 -vf scale=512:-1 \
 -ss 00:00:17 -to 00:00:22 STS-132_Liftoff_Space_Shuttle_Atlantis.gif
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what those commands do!

Comment: The question is about ImageMagick, not ffmpeg.

Comment: Answers that recommend a *solution* that uses a different tool from the one asked about [are generally considered okay](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15921/22949). However, @dieland167 I recommend you **[edit]** this to clarify if the method you're recommending works when the *input* is an animated gif--since that's essential to the *problem* described in the question--and to show at least one example of such usage (either in addition to, or instead of, the existing example).