# How do I create an animated gif from still images (preferably with the command line)?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, gif

I want make a `.gif` animated picture from a given set of `.jpg` pictures.

I would prefer to do it from the command line, so command line tools would be very welcome.

Comment: Works, very memory hungry though. There are LOADs of potential dupes though:http://askubuntu.com/questions/648244/how-to-create-gif-from-command-line http://askubuntu.com/questions/457351/are-there-softwares-available-on-ubuntu-for-the-conversion-of-a-series-of-image http://askubuntu.com/q/573712/178596 http://askubuntu.com/questions/566476/how-can-i-create-a-gif-out-of-a-sequence-of-png-files-without-the-previous-image http://askubuntu.com/questions/380875/loop-terminal-command-for-combining-png-to-gif-animation http://askubuntu.com/q/636149/178596

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) package. Install it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Now you can create a `gif` from number of pictures(`jpg`) using:

```
convert -delay 20 -loop 0 *.jpg myimage.gif
```

Comment: Please, include here how you resize the gif animation etc by 50%. Etc `-resize 50%`.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 failed with "cache resources exhausted" for these images: https://github.com/cirosantilli/media/blob/master/opengl-rotating-triangle.zip?raw=true related: https://superuser.com/questions/1178666/imagemagick-convert-quits-after-some-pages

Comment: ImageMagick users will likely also want: `-deconstruct`. I have also found that ImageMagick is very memory hungry, see benchmarks: https://askubuntu.com/a/1102183/52975

Comment: `convert -delay 0 -loop 0 *.tif myanimated.gif` worked nicely, on 720 tif files

Comment: awesome, you may change the delay according to your needs.

Comment: The comment by @CiroSantilli新疆再教育营六四事件法轮功郝海东 has links that solve the `cache resources exhausted` problem. However, I would love to understand why creating a measly 1.7MB GIF would require more than 1GB (which is the default in the `policy.xml` file) in cache resources

Answer (score 82):

To complete @Maythux answer:

#### To avoid generating a very large file, you can use `-resize` option:

In my case, I have 4608x3456 images and the generated gif was more than 300M for 32 images

```
convert -resize 20% -delay 20 -loop 0 *.jpg myimage.gif
```

or

```
convert -resize 768x576 -delay 20 -loop 0 *.jpg myimage.gif
```

#### Take care of *.jpg

`*.jpg` sucks a bit when dealing with numeric values, you may generate a gif with unsorted pics.

```
$ ls|cat
21-33-26_1.jpg
21-33-26_10.jpg   // <--- this one
21-33-26_2.jpg
21-33-26_3.jpg
21-33-26_4.jpg
21-33-26_5.jpg
21-33-26_6.jpg
21-33-26_7.jpg
21-33-26_8.jpg
21-33-26_9.jpg
21-33-28_1.jpg    // <--- should be here    
21-33-28_2.jpg
21-33-28_3.jpg
...
```

As the shots were taken very quickly (10/s) they all have the same modification time and you can't trick using `ls -t` for example. On ubuntu you can use `ls -v` instead, something like:

```
convert -resize 768x576 -delay 20 -loop 0 `ls -v` myimage.gif
```

Sorting numerically is quite tricky on Mac OS X though, I guess you'll need to build a custom script.

Comment: You can avoid your *.jpg issue by forward padding numbers with zeros. "01.jpg" instead of "1.jpg", and so on. If you get to triple digits, then "001.jpg", "010.jpg", etc.

Comment: There are several ways around the filename sequence problem. Including `find`, `sort`, brace expansion, and so on. The `ls` tool is notoriously unsuitable for this kind of thing. Use `find`. There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's worth it.

Comment: Some users might be interested in editing filenames with massren: https://github.com/laurent22/massren

Comment: it takes ages to finish. Is there a verbose option?

Comment: If the input has a transparent background, I would also recommend the `-dispose Background` option. (I realize OP's post is about jpeg images which cannot have transparent backgrounds, but just in case anyone finds this answer via Google, like I did).

By the way, regarding the `ls` sorting, you could always do some bash script hacking inline, e.g.: `$(for f in \`seq 0 10\`; do printf "21-33-26_$f.jpg\n"; done)`

Answer (score 53):

**ffmeg solution + test data**

As of Ubuntu 18.10, ffpmeg 4.0.2-2, ImageMagick 6.9.10-8, I have found that ffmpeg is much faster than ImageMagick, and uses [much less memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573712/convert-thousands-of-pngs-to-animated-gif-convert-uses-too-much-memory/573922#573922).

The simplest conversion command is:

```
ffmpeg \
  -framerate 60 \
  -pattern_type glob \
  -i '*.png' \
  -r 15 \
  -vf scale=512:-1 \
  out.gif \
;
```

You can get my test data with:

```
wget -O opengl-rotating-triangle.zip https://github.com/cirosantilli/media/blob/master/opengl-rotating-triangle.zip?raw=true
unzip opengl-rotating-triangle.zip
cd opengl-rotating-triangle
```

[image]

The test data was generated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191978/how-to-use-glut-opengl-to-render-to-a-file/14324292#14324292 and contains 256 1024x1024 PNG images.

And here is another test data that you can generate directly in your browser right now! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235286/convert-html5-canvas-sequence-to-a-video-file/57153718#57153718

[image]

The important `ffmpeg` options I want to highlight are:

- `-pattern_type glob`: convenient way to select images
- `-framerate 60`: assume 60 FPS on input images, and output the same FPS.

  `ffmpeg` cannot know otherwise, since there is no FPS data is in images as there is is in video formats.

  The 256 input frames take about 4 seconds to finish.

  `-r 15`: optional. Pick one every 4 images so reduce size (`4 == 60 / 15`).

  With it, `identify out.gif` says that the GIF contains only 64 frames.

  It still takes 4 seconds to play, so the delay is altered to make things match.
- `-vf scale=512:-1`: optional. Set the width, scale height proportionally, usually to reduce size and save space.

See also:

- video from images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg/37478183#37478183
- GIF from video: [How to create an animated GIF from MP4 video via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648603/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-mp4-video-via-command-line)

**ImageMagick vs ffmpeg benchmark**

To get ImageMagick to work, I first had to modify its disk and memory limits at `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` as explained at: https://superuser.com/questions/1178666/imagemagick-convert-quits-after-some-pages

I compared the commands:

```
/usr/bin/time -v convert *.png -deconstruct -delay 1.6 out-convert.gif
/usr/bin/time -v ffmpeg \
  -framerate 60 \
  -pattern_type glob \
  -i '*.png' \
  out-ffmpeg.gif \
;
```

The commands were constructed to produce outputs that are as close as possible to make the comparison valid:

- `/usr/bin/time -v`: used to find the maximum memory usage as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process
- `-deconstruct`: GIF images can contain just the minimal modified rectangle from the previous frame to make the GIF smaller.

  `ffmpeg` calculates those diffs by default, but ImageMagick does not, unless `-deconstruct` is used.

  You will basically want to use that option every time with ImageMagick.

  We can observe the difference with:

  ```
  identify out.gif
  ```

  With the compressed version, all frames have smaller sizes than the initial one, e.g.:

  ```
  out.gif[0] GIF 1024x1024 1024x1024+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 16.7865MiB 0.010u 0:00.010
  out.gif[1] GIF 516x516 1024x1024+252+257 8-bit sRGB 256c 16.7865MiB 0.010u 0:00.010
  out.gif[2] GIF 515x520 1024x1024+248+257 8-bit sRGB 256c 16.7865MiB 0.010u 0:00.010
  ```

  In this example, the second frame is only `516x516` instead of the full 1024x1024, and is placed at an offset of `252+257`. It therefore contains just the middle triangle.

  See also: [how can I resize an animated GIF file using ImageMagick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257831/how-can-i-resize-an-animated-gif-file-using-imagemagick/1104062#1104062)
- `-delay`: value that matches the 60FPS of `ffmpeg`. Should not matter for conversion performance, but I don't want to risk it.

The output GIFs have about the same size and look visually identical.

We get for ImageMagick:

```
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:56.16
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2676856
```

and for ffmpeg:

```
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:04.41
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 97172
```

from which we see that:

- ImageMagick used 2.6Gb of RAM and took about 1 minute
- ffmpeg used 100Mb of RAM and took 4 seconds

Test hardware: Lenovo ThinkPad [P51 laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/thinkpad/p-series/ThinkPad-P51/p/22TP2WPWP51), Intel Core i7-7820HQ, 32GB(16+16) DDR4 2400MHz SODIMM, 512GB SSD PCIe TLC OPAL2.

Comment: Upvoted and liked!, great answer, I have one small follow up question. I have not so much high quality images, and i did not use `-r ` and `-v` commands, still the output gif is of much lower quality than original png files. How to keep the same quality of gif as given png files?

Comment: Hi @astro123 how is the quality lower? Smaller image size, or less frames, or something else (GIF uses lossless apparently, so can't be worse compression)? Try `-framerate 60 -r 60`. Inspect the generated GIF and input images with ImageMagick tools like `identify` to try and figure out what is going on.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `palettegen` and `paletteuse` to get much better quality and lower file size, e.g. with `-filter_complex "[0:v] split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse"`. See: [giphy engineering](https://engineering.giphy.com/how-to-make-gifs-with-ffmpeg/).

Also, note that ffmpeg does not support transparent backgrounds, which is quite important for making animated emojis etc.

Answer (score 29):

Instead of modifying file names you can use globbing to get your shell to expand file names

```
convert -resize 50% -delay 10 -loop 0 image_{0..99}.jpg output.gif
```

Answer (score 20):

### GIMP

You can easily do this with GIMP. First install it if it's not installed already with

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

#### Creating the gif

From GIMP go to **File** -> **Open as Layers** to open all the png's on their own layer.

[image: Open as Layer]

From here you can perform edits on the layers and, once done, go to **File** -> **Export As**. From the dialog be sure to set the file type to GIF.

[image: Set file type to GIF]

From there you will go to the GIF export options. Tick the '*As Animation*' option and set the parameters as required.

[image: GIF export options]

#### To change the delay between frames

Modify the name of the layers, and include the delay in milliseconds between parenthesises, like this: `(1500ms)`

[image]

#### To preview the animation before exporting

Click "Filters" menu, then "Animation", then "Animation Playback".

Comment: 'Command line preferred' - from the question

Answer (score 5):

You can use a program called convert included in the imagemagick package. It is command line driven, but very easy to use. Install it either through the software center, or go to a command prompt and type

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Now to create the .gif.

```
convert -delay 100  -size 100x100 xc:SkyBlue \
          -page +5+10  balloon.gif   -page +35+30 medical.gif  \
          -page +62+50 present.gif   -page +10+55 shading.gif  \
          -loop 0  animation.gif
```

*Note the above example is straight from [Image Magick Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/)

Comment: How do I do 40 PNG images in a looping GIF? All in folder /home/fusion809/Documents/Images

Comment: @BH2017: `convert -delay 20 -loop 0 *.png out.gif` makes a looping GIF.

Answer (score 1):

To add something, you'll probably end with a huge GIF file with the `convert` variant proposed.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343340/4313009) answer in StackOverflow states, it's convenient to optimize the resulting GIF with something like the following:

```bash
mogrify -layers 'optimize' -fuzz 7% mygif.gif
```

With this I'm getting about 1/50 times the original size.

I've been getting trouble with the resources assigned to `ImageMagick`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699200/4313009) post can be helpful if it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the same convert command, but make sure to include `-dispose Background` to clear the canvas before adding the next frame. It looks like the following:

```
convert -delay 100 -dispose Background -loop 0 *.jpg animation.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

just use **ffmpeg** on the command line, it comes preinstalled on Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Debian and other linux

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt output.gif
```

your *list.txt* file should be arranged like this:

```
image001.jpg
duration 5
image002.jpg
duration 12
image003.jpg
duration 7
image004.jpg
duration 2
```

Comment: This is better than most solutions, since it gives flexibility in terms of durations for each frame. But lines should rather look like this: file 'image001.jpg'